# Postgres 'after insert or update' trigger isn't firing

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I've migrated our database from Oracle to Postgres. One of the steps is to save a copy of the record's status history. I do this via an INSERT, UPDATE trigger on the main table. The trigger checks to see if the status has changed and, if so, adds a record to the status history table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SAMPLE_STATUS_HISTORY_Trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
  IF( old.STATUS_CODE != new.STATUS_CODE ) THEN
    INSERT INTO SAMPLE_STATUS_HISTORY( analyte_status_history_id, sample_result_id, STATUS_CODE, status_date, status_user_id )
      VALUES( nextval('SAMPLE_ANALYTE_STATUS_HIST_SEQ'), new.sample_result_id, new.STATUS_CODE, new.status_date, new.status_user_id );
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SAMPLE_ANALYTE_STATUS_HIST
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON SAMPLE_RESULTS
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE SAMPLE_STATUS_HISTORY_Trigger()
;
```

I've ensured the trigger is bound to the table.

The main application is a .NET MVC app using NHibernate. Things work within a transaction, but the transactions are working for the main table's insert/updates.

My only guess is that I have a syntax error in the trigger logic but I'm not seeing the error if I manually run an insert or update statement.

Comment: I don't see a problem statement here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The INSERT with having a **null** value for ***old.*** was causing me issues when I tried @JGH's suggestion. I ended up with this code which just feels dirty:

```
  IF( TG_OP = 'INSERT' OR old.STATUS_CODE <> new.STATUS_CODE ) THEN
```

I still don't understand why the original code wouldn't work for UPDATE statements. The only difference between this and that is the **!=**. Maybe that's a syntax issue for plpgsql?

Either way, this appears to work from both a SQL window and the application.

Answer (score 1):

For `insert`, `OLD.?` is null so the inequality check will also return null.

Instead, use

```
IF( old.STATUS_CODE IS DISTINCT FROM new.STATUS_CODE ) THEN
```

Comment: I would think that the code would have still worked for UPDATE statements, right? I don't see that. BUT- I'll also try this out and see if it works.

Comment: That worked for an UPDATE but erroring on an INSERT: SQL Error: ERROR: record "old" is not assigned yet
  Detail: The tuple structure of a not-yet-assigned record is indeterminate.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function SAMPLE_STATUS_HISTORY_Trigger() line 3 at IF